# Squaring the equation of $4$ variables

Tags: polynomials, radicals, quadratic-forms

I have an equation of the following form

\begin{align}
A + B x + C y + D z = (E x + F y + G z) t
\end{align}

where $x, y, z, t$ are square roots of some other term and rest coefficients are constant. I want an equation containg $x^2, y^2, z^2, t^2$.
I started by squaring the terms but after few steps terms get messed up.

Anyone if can help me or suggest some nice way to rearrange so that above equation can be transformed into an equation containing $x^2, y^2, z^2, t^2$.

Comment: *I want an equation containg $x^2, y^2, z^2, t^2$.*  For what purpose?

Comment: to remove the square root powers in $x, y, z t$ so that i can solve the equation numerically as it will become in form of polynomial.

Comment: Why not find the solutions for $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$ and then square them?